# What type to return from a repository object?

Tags: php, repository-pattern

I'm trying implement a repository pattern in my application.

Currently, my views are tightly coupled with models.

For examples,

**View1.php**

```
foreach($news_rows ad $news) 
{
    echo $news->getPublishedDate();
}
```

As you see above, **view1.php** is accessing a method in the **$news** model.

Okay, let's say I have a news repository for my database models and that repository returns a new model or news models depending on the method called. Everything is going to work just fine.

In the future, if I switch my database to mongo or something else, I will not have the same model with the same method.

How should I approach this issue?

Should I return an array from now on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to go from SQL Server to MongoDB without changing the objects I was returning from the database layer very much.

To do this you would need to wrap the data layer in order to abstract it out. I implemented business entity objects that where independent of the database, row's mapped exactly to objects and had a concept of a id, but did not contain direct links to other entities data.